# Highchart hide series element with xAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have Highchart with series data and I want to hide() one data element, works correctly when I hide() the first element, but when I try to hide() second or any other element only data point is hidden, and the label xAxis does not disappear :(
Guys, could you explain to me why is this happening and how I can hide the entire element with highcharts-axis-labels?
Many thanks!

My jsfiddle code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/maxmsmax/b0wry15q/17/)

```
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Xalkori',
    data: [{
      x: 44,
      y: 1435
    }, {
      x: 44,
      y: 689
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Xofigo',
    data: [{
      x: 45,
      y: 14182
    }, {
      x: 45,
      y: 514
    }],
    visible: false,
  }, {
    name: 'Xtandi',
    data: [{
      x: 46,
      y: 9065
    }, {
      x: 46,
      y: 572
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Yervoy',
    data: [{
      x: 47,
      y: 42646
    }, {
      x: 47,
      y: 1395
    }]
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the amount of the xAxis labels, their visibility etc are independent on the chart point visibility.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7e90jwdL/

If you want to hide the xAxis labels base on the series visibility, you will need to do it programmatically.

Something like here:

```
events: {
  render() {
    let chart = this;

    chart.series.forEach(s => {
      if (!s.visible) {
        chart.xAxis[0].ticks[s.xData[0]].label.hide()
      } else {
        chart.xAxis[0].ticks[s.xData[0]].label.show()
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Be aware that this demo is just a showcase and it works fine if the series points x values are the same.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qn0tsdeh/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Comment: Hey Sebastian, thanks! If it's possible to completly hide xAxis point? https://www.screencast.com/t/uB4Egd9fV https://www.screencast.com/t/prkUvJSZXRB This works as I expect, when I hide the first element, it completely disappears along with xAxis point. For example: if I click hide() for series data point I need also to hide xAxis for that point. Show only the data where it exists. So show only 3 lines: 44, 45, 47, other 44.25, 44.5, 44.75, 45.25, 45.5, 45.75, 46, 46.25, 46.5, 46.75 - hide. Thank you

Comment: Hi @Sebastian do you know why I can't completely hide xAxis point and move visible positions closer to each other?

Comment: @Maksym could you reproduce this issue on some online editor?

Comment: Sure @Sebastian https://jsfiddle.net/maxmsmax/b0wry15q/23/ - for this one I see a lot free space between 44 and 47 because space is reserved for hidden 45 and 46. It's possible to hide this space like: https://jsfiddle.net/maxmsmax/b0wry15q/26/ ?

Comment: Notice that Highcharts is a tool to display the visual output of the data, the distance between points it's also a data thing, making it lower disturb the chart readability. Take a look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/tickpositions-tickpositioner/ to understand what I mean. 

I think that this is an output which you want to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/40rpL9gj/ I cannot see any other solution than rendering a custom legend to add/remove series and redraw the chart for recalculating axis labels

Comment: I got an error while trying to access xData from series type, You can use below code to fix it
chart.xAxis[0].ticks[s.data[0].category].label.hide()